# Understanding NDEF record format

Tags: javascript, nfc, ndef

I have written an NDEF text record - "poo" (just testing) to an NFC Forum type 2 tag, and I need some help understanding what exactly was written, and in what format. 
The command that was sent to the tag contains four arrays:

```
new Uint8Array([162, 4, 3, 10, 209, 1]).buffer                                                           
new Uint8Array([162, 5, 6, 84, 2, 101]).buffer                                                           
new Uint8Array([162, 6, 110, 112, 111, 111]).buffer  <-- 112, 111, 111 is ASCII for "poo"                                                 
new Uint8Array([162, 7, 254, 0, 0, 48]).buffer
```

I understand that the first byte of each array (162) is the "write" command. The second byte (4, 5, 6, 7) of each array is the index within the entire tag data to place the bytes that follow. It starts at 4 because the first 16 bytes have already been written, and contain metadata about the tag. 
I also understand that the 112, 111, 111 is the text I have stored.

So my question: **what is the purpose of the first two and last arrays?**

I cannot understand what data they contain. Here is the final content of my NFC tag (I have truncated all the zero's from the end)

```
new Uint8Array([95, 222, 208, 217, 54, 218, 237, 38, 39, 3, 0, 0, 225, 17, 96, 0, 3, 10, 209, 1, 6, 84, 2, 101, 110, 112, 111, 111, 254, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...])
```

As you can see the first 16 bytes were written upon creation; defining the tag. Following this are the 4 arrays from above. My current understanding stems from [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/ndef), which explains that the payload comes with metadata to explain what data type etc it is, but there are two arrays preceding the payload, and one after, which I don't understand.

Comment: What is the chipset of the tag? e.g. NTAG203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bashing my head against a wall for a  while, I figured out that it *is* metadata as I suspected, but it was in a different order to what is normally documented. More details on the below can be found [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/ndef).

```
new Uint8Array([162, 4, 3, 10, 209, 1]).buffer
3: "Type length"
10: "Record length"
209: "NDEF record header"
1: "Type Name Field"

new Uint8Array([162, 5, 6, 84, 2, 101]).buffer   
6: "Payload Length"
84: "Well known record"
2: "Well known record type" (in this case - the encoding for this text (UTF))
101: "e"

new Uint8Array([162, 6, 110, 112, 111, 111]).buffer
110: "n" - ("en" is locale)
112: "p"
111: "o"
111: "o"

new Uint8Array([162, 7, 254, 0, 0, 48]).buffer 
254: Marks the end of the payload
```

Answer (score 2):

It is NDEF meta data:

[image: structure]

You can match up the data to each of the fields above.

Comment: I actually saw this image before during my investigation, the problem is that this is a rather broad explanation of the metadata that was shown in the arrays. I needed a more specific explanation of each byte and what it meant - but I've got this now, as shown in my answer. Thanks anyway